# unable to access magento classes via command line interface/vagrant box

Tags: magento, vagrant, command-line-interface

i installed Magento via a [vagrant box](https://github.com/klierik/simple-magento-vagrant). it works fine.

However, i need to test code via CLI .i accordingly created a page at the root of the site with following code:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();


$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(79);
print_r($customer->getData());
```

i then tried to access this page  via command line interface on windows (cygwin) with following commands

```
php magento/test.php
```

i get the following errors;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [20 02] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
' in C:\DevFolder\magentoKlierik\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:12 9
```

however when i make the same call via the URL i get access. i.e

why is there a difference when using  command line and how do i give permission on the command line

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the code inside the vagrant box, so in this case you need to run in your host system:

```
vagrant ssh -c 'php /vagrant/httpdocs/test.php'
```

For more information you can refer to the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh.html).

Moreover I suggest you not to use custom scripts but use the system that is provided by magento for creating cli scripts.

You can find a good tutorial on [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/php-shell-scripts-for-magento/) (which I did not write) that provides you with some examples.